# "Britain’s recovery outstrips the world"

Tags: possessives

The title of one of the leading articles in today's (London's) Times is:

> Britain’s recovery outstrips the world

Shouldn't it be *Britain's recovery outstrips the world's*?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Because it's the world's recovery. If not, it raises the question, the world's what is being outstripped by Britain's recovery? Which is still possessive.

Answer (score 0):

Techically, yes it should be

> Britain's recovery outstrips the world's?

as the sentence is

> Britain’s recovery outstrips the world's recovery

or else should be

> Britain’s recovery outstrips the rest of the world

Comment: Technically, either one is correct. The important point is that the extra apostrophe and `S` take up space and provide no information, which is a no-no for headline writers. News headlines are **not** normal English, and do not follow normal English rules. Google on "crash blossoms" to see what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

Journalistic titles follow a grammar of their own. This particular title is fine:

> Britain's recovery outstrips the world

You could also say:

> Britain's recovery outstrips Germany

In both cases, there is an implication that "the world" refers to "the world's recovery":

> Britain's recovery outstrips the world['s recovery]
>
> Britain's recovery outstrips Germany['s recovery]

Dropping the "'s recovery" is not appropriate for normal English but it is acceptable in a journalistic title.